# Alternative method of making heightmap

Tags: c, opengl

I was thinking of creating a 2x2 array with randomly generated values which then be drawn using glVertex3i, for example:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
int x = 5;
int z = 5;
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
        glVertex3i(x, heightmap[i][j], z);
    }
    x -= 0.5;
    z -= 0.5;
}
glEnd();
```

The only problem I'm having is that, the map isn't drawn on the z dimension I think, because all I get is 1 side essentially.

What might be wrong? Obviously the algorithm is basic for now, but its just a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What might be wrong?

Let's start here:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
```

A polygon is *required* to be planar. All of the vertices must lie in a single plane. If they don't, then OpenGL is not responsible for how it gets rendered. You cannot draw a heightmap as a single polygon and expect to get reasonable results. You must draw triangles, either with a series of `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`s or with `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Then, there's what Christian said.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you mean

```
float x = 5.0f;
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
    float z = 5.0f;
    for (int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
        glVertex3f(x, heightmap[i][j], z);
        z -= 0.5f;
    }
    x -= 0.5f;
}
```

Or with `x` and `z` switched, depends on your convention. But first, don't subtract 0.5 from an int, it will draw the same vertex twice. And second, one variable needs to run in the inner loop, the other in the outer loop. Or did I misundertand the question?

And are you sure you want the whole heightmap to make up a single polygon? Maybe I really misunderstood the question?